Change variable/method color in black apps script theme
I'm using the addon Black Apps Script to create a visual theme in Google Apps Script. My actual code works well for all tokens except variables and methods/functions have the same color (token "identifier" color)
{
    "base": "vs-dark",
    "colors": {
        "editor.background": "#1B1D1E",
        "editor.foreground": "#D8DEE9",
        "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#282A2B",
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#5FB3B3",
        "editorCursor.foreground": "#FFCC00",
        "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#404040"
    },
    "inherit": true,
    "rules": [
        {
            "fontStyle": "italic",
            "foreground": "7A8288",
            "token": "comment"
        },
        {
            "foreground": "B8CC52",
            "token": "string"
        },
        {
            "foreground": "00B0FF",
            "token": "keywords"
        },
        {
            "foreground": "F78C6C",
            "token": "number"
        },
        {
            "fontStyle": "bold",
            "foreground": "FFAB00",
            "token": "type"
        },
        {
            "foreground": "FF4081",
            "token": "delimiter"
        },
        {
            "foreground": "95E6CB",
            "token": "regexp"
        },
        {
            "foreground": "FFFFFF",
            "token": "identifier"
        }
    ]
}

I tried using multiple tokens as seen on the internet like
{
    "foreground": "C6FF00",
    "token": "variable.parameter"
},
{
    "foreground": "FFD700",
    "token": "entity.name.function"
}

but nothing works to separate the viewing color, I don't know what tokens use or how to build the theme to have an unique color for the variables.
Any help? Thanks!!
